# Extracting elements from unique IDs in json file

Tags: json, stata

I want to extract a series of elements from a `json` file in which each item is listed under a unique ID and write them into a dataset in Stata using the *community-contributed* command `insheetjson`.

The data looks as follows:

```
{
    "4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8": {
        "name": "Carmen Fraga Estévez",
        "country": "es",
        "group": "epp",
        "lqdn": "https://memopol.lqdn.fr/europe/parliament/deputy_from_ep_id/1993/",
        "agw": null,
        "email": "carmen.fragaestevez@europarl.europa.eu",
        "firstname": "Carmen",
        "surname": "Fraga Estévez",
        "title": "Ms",
        "salutation": "Dear Ms Fraga Estévez,",
        "parltrack_id": 1993,
        "active": true,
        "committees": [
            {
                "id": "pech",
                "role": "Member"
            }
        ],
        "urls": {
            "rss": "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/rss/mep/carmen.fragaestevez/en.xml",
            "europarl": "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/1993/_history.html",
            "photo": "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/mepphoto/1993.jpg"
        },
        "constituency": "es_pp"
 }
}
```

I want to extract the `name`, `country`, and if there is a committee, the `id` and `role`.

Each element in the `json` file has a unique ID number (but each starts with something like `4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8`).

I have tried the following code in Stata:

```
gen str240 name=""
gen str240 country=""
gen str240 id=""
gen str240 role=""

insheetjson name country id role using mep.json, col("name" "country" "id" "role")
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error code in Stata:

```
{err: Invalid column name/selector 'name'. (Possible name candidates are: "4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8" "4f1ac789b819f25efd000092"
```

And it then proceed to list out all the unique ID numbers in the `json` file.

Comment: Hi, sorry.  Last time I posted a question someone said that I should include the code in the text instead of linking to a file.  Here's the json file I want to use: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lobbyplag/lobbyplag-data/master/data/mep.json

Comment: I have updated your example. In order to generalize this you will have to loop over elements.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for your example:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate str240 name=""
generate str240 country=""
generate str240 id=""
generate str240 role=""

insheetjson name ///
            country ///
            id ///
            role ///
            using mep.json, ///
            col("4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8:name" ///
                "4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8:country" ///
                "4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8:committees:1:id" ///
                "4f1ac817b819f25efd0000c8:committees:1:role")

compress

list

     +------------------------------------------------+
     |                 name   country     id     role |
     |------------------------------------------------|
  1. | Carmen Fraga Estévez        es   pech   Member |
     +------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi yes, thank you.  That works for one observation, but I want to be able to collect that information for ALL observations (754) in the json file that each have a unique ID number.  Perhaps there's a way to create a loop to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: There is but it is too much work and i do not have the inclination to do all your work for you. With my answer and the help file you can figure it out.